# how to get all fields in the query with aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i am trying this aggregation i got the exact out put but not get all fields please solve my problem how to get all fields in following query

```
db.lights.aggregate({     $match: {         CREATE_DATE: {             $gte: ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z"),             $lt: ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:30.000Z")         }     } }, {     $addFields: {         offduration: {             $divide: [{                 $subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]             }, 3600000]         }     } }, {     "$group": {         _id: {             SWITCHID: "$SWITCHID",             STATUS: "$STATUS"         },         avgduration: {             $avg: "$offduration"         },         SWITCHID: {             $first: "$SWITCHID"         },         CREATE_DATE: {             $first: "$CREATE_DATE"         },         RECEIVEDDATE: {             $first: "$RECEIVEDDATE"         },         STATUS: {             $first: "$STATUS"         },         offduration: {             $first: "$offduration"         },     } }, {     $project: {         _id: 0,         SWI`TCHID: 1,         CREATE_DATE: 1,         RECEIVEDDATE: 1,         STATUS: 1,         avgduration: '$avgduration',         offduration: '$offduration'     } },{"$group" : {     _id: {         SWITCHID: "$SWITCHID"     },     on_minus_off: { $sum:{ "$cond": [         { "$eq": ["$STATUS", "LIGHTS OFF"] },         "$avgduration",         { $subtract: [ 0, "$avgduration" ] }     ]}} }})
```